# Can my cisco C220 run on 220v instead of 110v and if so, how do i change it?

Tags: cisco, electrical-power

We have both 220v and 110v power at our data center, but have more capacity left on the 220v circuit so i would like to put our new c220 server on it.  What does it take to make this happen?

Answer (score 3):

According to the spec sheet: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/ps10265/ps10493/C220M3_SFF_SpecSheet.pdf

you can simply plug it into the 220 pdu if you have one, just need the right power cord (found here on the same spec sheet): http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/ps10265/ps10493/C220M3_SFF_SpecSheet.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, thx for the information

Comment: Welcome @user186324 - if this answers your question please accept as the answer.